# Retrieve data of a get request as a result of Post request in python

Tags: python, html, sockets, http, python-requests

I'm trying to automate the Data Retrieving procedure of a specific form in my company with **python request library**; therefore, here's my issue:
there is a form in which a user can choose different filters to send a **Post** request to the server in order to retrieve an excel-like table as a result. **I want to know how I can place a sequence of Post and Get requests to retrieve data provided by the server.**

**More info**: I have checked the network behavior of the page at Chrome:

1. the Post request containing Form-Data
2. another post request with a different URL without form-data
3. two get requests for PNG
4. a post same as #1
5. finally a get request where the page will be loaded completely

Comment: Which framework are you using as a backend? Flask, Django or something else?

Comment: web frameworks: MicrosoftASP.Net web server: IIS / Microsoft HTTPAPI

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) library is pretty self-explanatory in this regard. The following sample of code can help you in your task.

```
import requests
r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

Comment: I know this already, but it just sent a post request with my own payload...how can I retrieve data from the Get request after that?